# OCR validations with Rails building a business card scanner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ocr

My goal is to write a validation class for Rails that is capable of using an OCR recognised text from a business card and is able to detect string snippets and assign them to the correct attributes. I know this cannot be probably 100% perfect but I want to get as close as possible. Here is my approach so far:

1. I scan business cards via jquery's `navigator.mediaDevices`
2. I send the scanned image to a third party API Service, called OCRSpace (a gem is available here: https://github.com/suyesh/ocr_space)
3. I then get a unformatted array of recognised text snippets back, for example:

`result = [['John Doe'], ['+49 160 123456'], ['Mainstr. 45a'], ['12345 Berlin'], ['CEO'], ['johndoe@business-website.de'], ['www.business-website.de']]`

- I then iterate through the array and do some checks, for example
- Using the `people` library (https://github.com/mericson/people)
  to split the name in firstname and lastname (additionally the title
  or middlenames) Using the `phonelib` library
  (https://github.com/daddyz/phonelib) to look up a valid phone number
  and format it in an international string
- Doing a basic regex check on    the email address and store it

What I miss now is:

1. How can I find out what the name-string would possibly be? Right now I let the user choose it (in my example he defines "John Doe" as the name and then the library does the rest). I'm sure I would run into conflicts when using a regex as strings like "Main Street" would then also be recognized as a name?
2. How do I regex a combination of ZIP-Code and City name? I'm not a regex expert, do you know any good sources that would help? Couldn't find any so far except some regex-checkers in general.

In general: Do you like my approach or is this way too complicated? And do you know some best-practices that look better?

Comment: did you manage to make it work ? is it possible to see how you did please?

Answer (score 0):

Don't consider this a full answer, but it was too much to make it a comment.
Your way of working seems Ok but I wouldn't use the OCR Service since there are other ways , [Tesseract](https://github.com/meh/ruby-tesseract-ocr) is the best known.

If you do and all the results are comparible presented it seems not too difficult since every piece of info has it's own characteristics.

You can identify the name part because it won't have numbers in it, the rest does, also you can expect to contain it "Mr." or "Mrs." or the such and not "Str.", "street" and so on. You could also use Google Maps to check for correct adresses, there are Ruby gems but have no experience with them.

Your people gem could also help.

You could guess all of this, present the results in you webpage and let the user confirm or adjust.

You could also RegExpr the post-city combination by looking fo a number and string combination in either order but you could also use a gem like [ZipCodes](https://github.com/monterail/zip-codes) to help.

I'm sorry, don't have the time now to test some Regular Expressions now and I don't publish code without testing.

Hope this was some help, success !

Comment: Thanks. I already wrote some regex, e.g. ```[0-9]{5}(\s)[A-Za-zäüö\s.]{3,20}``` would be a good one for the zip+city combo. But tesseract I would not recommend. I have tried it and its not very solid. I'd rather use the new google cloud services instead.

Comment: ok, it's a long time ago i tested tesseract, I suggested it because it's local versus a service where you depend upon (and is not free ?)